# Internet explorer browser is processing my code very wierd

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, browser

Inset the following code into a basic test.html file on your desktop.
Run using google chrome, firefox and internet explorer.

It fails to work in IE!

I see no reason why this code should malfunction. 
If you know why please try to fix this.
Is there some css commands incompatible with ie or do i need to target the specific browser with a specific peice of code...(which i dont like to do).

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #A3A3A3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #7D7D7D, #7D7D7D 80px, transparent 87px,   transparent 140%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#maincontainer {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 942px;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: ridge;
  border-color: #919191;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="maincontainer">


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If HTML/CSS is going to fail anywhere, it'll fail in IE. This is no surprise to anyone. Without being specific, it is likely that you'll need to modify something, either as an alternative for IE, or a different approach that works in all browsers.

Comment: I don't have time to set up a page run through several browsers to identify some non-specific problem. Edit your question to include more information. Start with with which version of IE is failing, and describe what should happen, and what doesn't. Then, maybe, someone will take a more detailed look.

Comment: Which version of IE? [`rgba()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors) is supported since IE9, and [`linear-gradient()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) is supported since IE10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer part of your question, RGBA as a background color isn't supported in IE8 and earlier. I ran into this problem a while back, and used this along with background-color RGBA for IE support:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7FFFFFFF', EndColorStr='#7FFFFFFF');
```

"7FFFFFFF" - First two characters are transparency amount, last 6 are color. All in hex

More information about gradients for IE can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: where would i insert this code? It seemed to have broken the design. Also.... just putting it out there but ie compatability view seems to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that many people are moving away from CSS and are moving to SVG for gradients.

If you take this code paste into notepad and name it: bkg.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myLinearGradient1"
                    x1="0%" y1="0%"
                    x2="0%" y2="100%"
                    spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#7D7D7D" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset=".92" stop-color="#7D7D7D" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0D0D0D" stop-opacity=".0"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100%" height="87px"
     style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient1);" />
</svg>
```

and your html should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">

   html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      background: #A3A3A3;
      background-image: url("svg-gradient.svg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }

   #maincontainer {
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 942px;
      min-width: 600px;
      margin: auto;
      border: ridge;
      border-color: #919191;
      border-top: 0;
      border-bottom: 0;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
      padding-left: 16px;
      padding-right: 16px;
   }

   </style>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="maincontainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This gave me the result you were looking for in chrome, firefox, and IE9.

reference:
[css-gradients-for-ie9](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/29/css-gradients-for-ie9/)

Comment: this doesnt in any way create the triple column i was looking for.

Comment: what does my solution not give you?  If you look at this [picture](http://i.imgur.com/vsXJPl6.png), your version is on top and mine is on bottom other than some color tweaking, it is the same.

Comment: By this i mean, it creates the triple column but not the top bar gradient that lightens the insides. Try to run my code in chrome and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<!doctype html>` at the top of your document to identify it as a Standards mode document. Use the F12 Developer Tools to ensure that your page isn't running in Compatibility Mode.

Comment: NOOOPE! That only fixes 1 peice of it (i forgot to include it in the quest). I actuallyt already had a doctype in the actual script. I can tell you haven't attempeted the code yourself because you would know the answer is far more complicated.